# Finding a complex function

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

[image]
What I feel there can't be any such function..but what if we assume a piecewise function? Will that be ok if we assume it like that..?

What's the proper approach to this question. And furthermore, I don't know what is meant by $A(z=0)$ I just assumed it may be analytic at $z=0$
 The boundary condition shows discontinuity..so it may not be analytic. So I thought there can't be such function

Comment: How can we determine the proper approach for the question? We can't even see what the question is!

Comment: I have attached an image related to it... You can't see ?

Comment: Here it is https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ANLb.jpg

Comment: I can, but it's only a fragment of a question. I only have your tags to suggest that this has something to do with complex analysis. What are we assuming about the function $f$?

Comment: This problem needs restating. Is $f$ holomorphic? Where? Etc ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, I think that the point is that since $f(z)=z$ for $z={1\over2n}$, the identity is the only possible analytic function satisfying the condition in a neighborhood of $0$.  (Two analytic functions that agree on a set with a limit point are identical.)  But $f$ is clearly not the identity, so there is no such functions.